# How to get facebook friend requests with javascript?

Tags: javascript

I want to create chrome extension, where i get all friend requests in popup.But i don't know how can i get  friend requests with content.js. Can someone help me please? do you know how can i get friend requests with javascript? i tried it with jquery ajax and fetch but it did not do anything. then i tried to get it in content.js but i can't get divs i need.

content.js

```
 let req = $('.clearfix.ruUserBox._3-z.friendRequestItem').length;
console.log(req);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Facebook's website has a [great example](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v6.0/user/friendrequests). You need to use the api endpoint of `/me/friendrequests`

```
/* make the API call */
FB.api(
    "/me/friendrequests",
    function (response) {
      if (response && !response.error) {
        /* handle the result */
      }
    }
);
```

Comment: thanks,but it gets me an error"Uncaught ReferenceError: FB is not defined",  Is something required before i write this code in content.js?

Comment: You need to add the code they show in the [Javascript SDK Quickstart](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/quickstart).

Answer (score 1):

Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> (for Chrome),
 <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> (for FireFox) to open the JavaScript Console. Paste the code in the console and press <kbd>enter</kbd> to run the code. If done correctly your pending friend requests will get confirmed one by one in a matter of seconds.